# Qiskit quantum fourier transform

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

We have 4 numbers x = [x1, x2, x3, x4]

We want to prepare quantum state Psi somehow to encode x

We want to make QFT on Psi to get Phi = QFT (Psi)

I have no idea how to approach this on qiskit

Comment: Have you read this? It gives example code: https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/quantum-fourier-transform.html

Comment: I have, but I would like to encode numbers in the states before I do the transform. Unless im too much of a noob i cant see it